# Android like Toasts for WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I wan't to inform the user over some processes (e.g. Login successfully/failed or something else). In Android I used the Toasts Messages to let them show a short time. For WP 8.1 I tried the ToastNotificationManager to get the same results. Unfortunately the wp-toast has an audio signal and it spams the notification center.

I checked the Libs Toastinet and coding4fun toolkit toast, but this libs are WP 8.0 / Silverlight only and I need a solution for WP Runtime 8.1.

Comment: ToastNotificationManager is the right way to go. From your code you can change/disable the audio signal, but not whether a banner is displayed or whether it's spamming the notification center. However, you can tell your users to do so in the WP settings. There users can enable/disable banners, vibration, audio, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set which sound to play by setting the audio element in the toast's xaml. This can be set to [silent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761492.aspx#no_sound) if appropriate.

You can control how your toasts appear in the action center by setting properties on the ToastNotification object or in the X-WNS- headers sent to WNS. This allows grouping, tagging, expiring, removing, etc. See [Managing toast notifications in action center (Windows Phone Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631259.aspx) on MSDN for details.

That said, if you're talking about notifications during the ordinary running of the app you may not want to use toasts. You may be better off showing warnings and such in-line or in your own screen-top panel (the latter is more important for Windows than Windows Phone, since toasts look quite different on each).

See [Guidelines and checklist for toast notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465391.aspx) and [Choosing the right UI surfaces: Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh465330(v=win.10).aspx#toasts__or_banners_).